# Listening for applications opening and closing in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I currently have a little script that opens two programs simultaneously:

```
@echo off

start "" "D:\...\Hearthstone Beta Launcher.exe"
start "" "C:\...\Innkeeper.exe"

exit
```

This works, but now I would also like to exit the Innkeeper process when I close Hearthstone.

However, there's an extra difficulty: `Hearthstone Beta Launcher.exe` actually opens a third program, the `battle.net` client, through which you then open the `Hearthstone.exe` itself.

So essentially, I would like to amend the batch script to do the following:

1. Start `Hearthstone Beta Launcher.exe`
2. Start `Innkeeper.exe`
3. Wait for `Hearthstone.exe` to open
4. Wait for `Hearthstone.exe` to close
5. Terminate `Innkeeper.exe` and the `battle.net` client
6. Gloriously self-destruct (a.k.a. `exit`)

Is such listening possible in batch, and if so, how would it be done?

(I would also be happy with solutions using something other than batch.)

Comment: use [tasklist](https://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html) and [taskkill](https://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found and modified a batch script that should work well for what it sounds like you need. It starts the two programs, waits for it to open, waits for it to close, then it terminates the programs and closes. You might want to change `Hearthstone Beta Launcher.exe` to have no spaces. Here is the script.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
color 07

set "EXE1=Hearthstone Beta Launcher.exe"
set "EXE2=Inkeeper.exe"
set "WAITEXE=Hearthstone.exe"
set "p1=Inkeeper.exe"
set "p2=battle.net"

rem ---- Opens Hearthstone and Innkeeper ----
start "" "%EXE1%" || echo Unable to start %EXE1%.
start "" "%EXE2%" || echo Unable to start %EXE2%.

rem ---- Waits for Hearthstone.exe to Open ----
:wait1
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %WAITEXE%" 2>NUL | find /I /N "%WAITEXE%">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto RUNNING1 & echo %EXE1% is running... else (
goto wait1
)

:RUNNING1

rem ---- Optional Running Code Here ----

rem ---- Waits for Hearthstone Beta Launcher.exe to Close ----
:wait2
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %WAITEXE%" 2>NUL | find /I /N "%WAITEXE%">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto wait2 else (
goto end
)

rem ---- Kills Program 1 and 2 ---- 

:end
cls
TASKKILL /F /IM %p1% /T || echo Unable to kill %p1%.
TASKKILL /F /IM %p2% /T || echo Unable to kill %p2%.
echo.
echo %p1% and %p2% have been terminated.
echo.
timeout 5
exit
```

Comment: This is very close to the solution I implemented after Stephan's comment. I used `for /f "usebackq" %%A in (\`tasklist /fi "imagename eq Hearthstone.exe" ^| find /v /c "" \`) do set shouldwait=%%A` and then `if /i "%shouldwait%" LEQ 1`, but your solution is cleaner and works better (I ran into some problems with my approach).

Comment: Thanks, the code is pretty basic and you should be able to adapt it easily to your needs if wanted. I tried to make it as basic and easy to customize as possible, hope it works nicely for whatever your doing.